# How does jest and babel work in tandem and link to each other to transpile ES6?

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs, babel-jest

I have a very simple test in Jest that that checks if the autoplay functionality of a plugin works fine , the code looks like below:

```
import html from './html.js';
import Glide from '../dist/glide.esm.js';


describe('check autoplay option' , () => {
    // console.log( document );

    beforeEach( () => {
        document.body.innerHTML = html;
    });

    test( 'Check index to be 1 for autoplay' , (done) => {

           let glide = new Glide('#glide' , {
                type : 'slider',
                gap : 0,
                autoplay: 500,
                rewind: false
           }).mount();

           setTimeout( () => {
                console.log( `The glide index is ${glide.index}` );
                expect( glide.index ).toBe(1);
                done();
           }, 510 );

    });

});
```

As you can see i am using the `import` statement in my jest test , which is not supported by default in jest , so if i just run the test file as is , an error stating that the import statement is not supported will be thrown. So i install the following too , in my package.json file. ( `"@babel/core": "^7.5.0", "@babel/preset-env": "^7.5.0", "babel-jest": "^24.8.0",` ).

```
//package.json
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.5.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.5.0",
    "babel-jest": "^24.8.0",
    "jest": "^24.8.0"
}
```

And have the `babel.config.json` file with the following settings:

```
// babel.config.js
module.exports = {
    presets: [
      [
        '@babel/preset-env',
        {
          targets: {
            node: 'current',
          },
        },
      ],
    ],
};
```

Now when i run `npm run test` , my test runs , my question is how does babel and jest work in tandem ? What exactly here is linking babel to the jest test ?

**P.S.** Have uploaded my test package to a git repo [here](https://github.com/gautamz07/TestTheJest/).

Comment: *"What exactly here is linking babel to the jest test ?"* - ...[`babel-jest`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-jest)?

Comment: @jonrsharpe thanks jonsharpe for the insights, but what about `bable.config.js` ,  if i delete this file , the import error still shows

Comment: Yes, you need the config to tell Babel *how* to transform your code.